# SQL Server 2000 query error

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2000

When I attempt to run on the SQL Server 2000 to a query which was developed for SQL Server 2008, I receive the following the error.

> ambiguous column name SucNo

Here is my query:

```
 SELECT
   p.SiraNo, p.SucNo, p.Fail, p.SucAdi, p.SucTarihi, p.Musteki, p.Supheli,
   (select f.AdiSoyadi as Kayıp_Şahıs where f.SucYili = '2011') as Kayıp_Şahıs,
   p.EvrakEksigi, p.EvrakSorumlusu, p.SevkTarihi, p.evrakSevkDurumu,
   p.sucYili as Yıl
 FROM pStationTbl p
 LEFT JOIN kayipTbl f ON p.SucNo = f.SucNo
 WHERE p.SucYili = '2011' 
 ORDER BY CASE evrakSevkDurumu
   When 'Beklemede' Then 1
   WHEN 'İkmal Edildi' Then 2
   Else 3
 End, SucNo DESC
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to qualify `SucNo DESC` in the `ORDER BY` i.e. `p.SucNo DESC`.

Presumably the SQL2000 query processor can't deduce that `f.SucNo` and `p.SucNo` resolves to the same sort, whereas SQL2008 can.